# Imageview Inside Cardview Has A Image Src Which Bounds Out Of Imageview

Tags: xamarin.android

I have a CardView with rounded corners, inside the CardView a ImageView is present.The issue is when i add the source inside the image the image goes out of ImageView hiding the round corners.

I have tried the code given below on macBook pro which produced the following results :

```
`<android.support.v7.widget.CardView
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:elevation="10dp"
        app:cardCornerRadius="10dp"
        android:layout_margin="5dp"
        app:cardPreventCornerOverlap="false" >
        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/card_view_image"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:src="@drawable/competition_background"
            android:scaleType="fitXY"
        />
    </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>`
```

Comment: I have a screen shot of the error , but i dont know how to upload it on stack overflow , can someone please guide me.

Comment: [link](https://wetransfer.com/downloads/f2c44a18801250c6f3174095fd3bf16620190326084158/6fd311) this is the produced images result, this is a we transfer link ,sorry for all the trouble

Answer (score 0):

Try setting a defined width and height for your imageview. If your image is very large it will expand beyond the cardview. You could also choose to reduce the size of the image, which will result in a smaller apk. This is something to keep in mind when developping an android application. Never add larger resources than needed to your project.

So you could try something like this:

```
<android.support.v7.widget.CardView
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:elevation="10dp"
        app:cardCornerRadius="10dp"
        android:layout_margin="5dp"
        app:cardPreventCornerOverlap="false" >
        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/card_view_image"
            android:layout_width="100dp"
            android:layout_height="100dp"
            android:src="@drawable/competition_background"
            android:scaleType="fitXY"
        />
    </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>`
```

Another option is to add match_parent to your imageview but add a margin so it not expanded to the corners of your cardview:

```
<android.support.v7.widget.CardView
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:elevation="10dp"
        app:cardCornerRadius="10dp"
        android:layout_margin="5dp"
        app:cardPreventCornerOverlap="false" >
        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/card_view_image"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_margin="12dp"
            android:src="@drawable/competition_background"
            android:scaleType="fitXY"
        />
    </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>`
```

Comment: The second option you mentioned , actually i have already tried it . It puts the image inside the ImageView but doesn't provide the curved corners for image instead it leaves the blank background of image view which doesn't satisfy my requirements.The first option , I will try it for sure.